# only change particular font-size dynamically in the application

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fonts

I am creating a web app in asp.net C#,

I have 50/60 pages with 4/5 master page which is working fine but now I want to allow my users to set the font size for particular area's

like I have these div's

```
<div>
   <label>this label has 14 as font color</label>
</div>

<div>
   <label>this label has 18 as font color</label>
</div>

<div>
   <label>this label has 22 as font color</label>
</div>

<div>
   <label>this label has 8 as font color</label>
</div>
```

now I just want to change the font-size of div which have 14 as font-size,

and I can't differentiate all the div the only information I know is I want to dynamically change the font-size of the div which have 14 as font-size,

I will use javascript and jquery to change the font-size of those div's

below is how exactly I did,

```
$('div label').css({ 'font-size': window.getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('font-size') });
```

but this changes the font-size of all the div and I just want to change the font size of div with 14px as font-size,

how can I achieve this?

Comment: you need something to uniquely identify each font for each label i suggest you use a class or a attribute

Comment: @madalinivascu yes I thinks the same but the application is very vast it will be very difficult to change the particular font-size in whole application

Comment: Can you add css classes?

Comment: no, I can't because the application is very vast, If I could then I did not need to ask question here

Comment: how do you know which element has which font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop all `label` and check if `font-size` is `14px`

```js
$('div label').each(function() {
if($(this).css('font-size')=='14px')
{ 
  $(this).css({ 'font-size': window.getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('font-size') })
}
});
```

```css
.fz-14{
font-size:14px;
}
.fz-18{
font-size:18px;
}
.fz-22{
font-size:22px;
}
.fz-8{
font-size:8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <label class="fz-14">this label has 14 as font color</label>
</div>

<div>
   <label class="fz-18">this label has 18 as font color</label>
</div>

<div>
   <label class="fz-22">this label has 22 as font color</label>
</div>

<div class="fz-8">
   <label>this label has 8 as font color</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `each()` to loop through all the *label*'s to check the *font-size* and set the property if required:

```js
$('div label').each(function(i, el){
  var fSize=window.getComputedStyle(el.parentNode).getPropertyValue('font-size');
  if(fSize == '14px')
    $(el).parent().css({ 'font-size': window.getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('font-size') });
});
console.log($('div').eq(1).css('font-size')); //16px
console.log($('div').eq(3).css('font-size')); //16px
```

```css
div{
  font-size: 20px;
}

div:nth-of-type(2n){
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <label>this label has 14 as font color</label>
</div>

<div>
   <label>this label has 18 as font color</label>
</div>

<div>
   <label>this label has 22 as font color</label>
</div>

<div>
   <label>this label has 8 as font color</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through all the div's. 
"$('div label')" This would always point to the first element.
I have linked for your reference.

```
$("div").each(function(){
  var fontSize = $(this).find('label').css("font-size");
  console.log("size", fontSize);
  if(fontSize <= "14px"){
     // your code
  }
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tanuj916/xpvt214o/979951/)